# Rewrite URL of custom taxonomies associated with WP_User in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 custom taxonomies associated with users, registered like this:

```
register_taxonomy('type', 'user', $args);
register_taxonomy('city', 'user', $args);
```

I want to have these URLs:

- domain.com/type/ (archive, listing users matching 'type').
- domain.com/type/city/ (archive, listing users corresponding to 'type' and 'city')
- domain.com/type/city/user/ (profile, showing user details)

Is it possible to have this friendly URL structure without the taxonomy names as a base?

Comment: From the documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/ you can use rewrire and add custom base. You will need to create relationships.  Also read post_link and post_type_link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/

Comment: The problem is that the customer does not want to use a base, he wants a URL only with the taxonomy names, for SEO advantages.

domain.com/expert/madrid/john/ where 'expert' belongs to the 'type' taxonomy (expert, rokkie,...), 'madrid' belongs to the 'city' taxonomy (Madrid, Barcelona, London,...) and 'john' is the user. In this case the user's profile would be shown.

Also domain.com/expert/madrid/ (list of experts in Madrid) and domain.com/expert/ (list of experts) should be accessible.

The modification of the links is done, the problem is where to point them with the rewrite rules.

Comment: As i said you should look in to post_type_link and rewrite argument for taxonomies. Here is a example - https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-taxonomy-term-custom-post-permalinks-wordpress/ . In post_type_link create conditions if you are on taxonomie A page or taxonomie B page from there get relationship and modify url.

Comment: And as I said, I need taxonomies to have no base.

I don't want something like: domain.com/type/expert/city/madrid/john/ but this domain.com/expert/madrid/john/

Nevertheless, thank you for your time.